# docx to image conversion using Python

Tags: python

I have a `docx` file which has multiple pages in it, and I have to convert each page to an `image`. 
Is there a way of doing it using Python?

What I have been able to do so far is convert the docx into pdf then from pdf to images using `pdf2image`
Is there a direct way of doing it from `docx` to `images`?

I have the same requirement for converting `pptx` to `images`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't you use MS Word and MS Powerpoint to convert them? Is Python a necessity? You can explore this API: https://www.convertapi.com/docx-to-jpg. Scroll down to see the python snippet.

Comment: You can give a try to this if there is not direct one.  docx -> pdf - > image
https://pypi.org/project/docx2pdf/

Comment: How did you convert docx into pdf?

Answer (score -1):

I tried every way to do that but I was unable to find any "direct" way of converting Docx or documents file to images. As @[Abins Chittilappillly James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12130167/abins-chittilappillly-james) Mentioned you need to convert it to pdf first I am just giving another shorter or easier way of doing that with my code. I Read some documents on the Microsoft website and didn't find any way to convert or export docx to jpg or image. Link to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.exportasfixedformat).

This is my code:-

```
#This code only convert docx to pdf and for pdf to img you can google it.
import win32com.client

Application = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
document_file = Application.Documents.Open(r'Your\Word\Document\file\path.docx')
document_file.ExportAsFixedFormat(r"Your\output\file\path.pdf", 17) #17 for PDF and 18 for XPS file format
Application.Quit()
```

Comment: @KJ But, It converts into images in an XPS file, not in the python program you cant access those images and store them in another file format as jpeg or png using the python program.

Comment: The output file from xps format is not a zip it is only a normal xps file .

Comment: hmm, I tried but I only have (_rels, Pages, Structure, FixedDoc.fdoc) no Resources and images in any directory.

Comment: aah ok thanks for trying to help, thank youT

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

You can use Pdf4me Python Lib. Please see

1. First you need to convert to PDF
   https://developer.pdf4me.com/docs/api/basic-functionality/convert-to-pdf/
2. Then convert your PDF to Image.
   https://developer.pdf4me.com/docs/api/basic-functionality/create-image/

Please let me know.

Comment: Thanks @Abins, I have already taken the approach you have mentioned, but i was looking for a way to directly convert the docx to images without having an intermediate pdf file